# Как задать значения для SharedPreferences при установке приложения?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-shared-preferences

Для хранения настроек Android-приложения хочу использовать SharedPreferences. Но как я понял они изменяются уже в процессе работы программы. А как задать их начальные значения которые они имеют когда приложение только установленно?

Answer (score 6):

Когда вы получаете значение из `SharedPreferences`, нужно также задать значение, которое вернётся, если по этому ключу ещё ничего не было записано.

Например:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("имя файла", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int value = sharedPref.getInt("ключ", 5);
```

В данном случае, мы получим записанное в файл значение, если оно там есть. Иначе мы получим число 5. Так можно задать значения по умолчанию.

Несложно будет сделать сброс настроек до изначальных.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("имя файла", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.apply();
```

Все записанные значения из файла удалятся, и мы снова будем получать дефолтные значения, пока туда что-нибудь не запишем.

Answer (score 3):

Ели в приложении есть `PreferenceActivity` или фрагмент, то там устанавливается значение по умолчанию для каких то параметров, это можно сделать программно, а можно по простому через `XML`. Вот , меню, например, для настройки текста в активности, 
а `key` это ключ по которому можно достучаться до настройки.

```
menu.xml:
 <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/entry_values"
        android:entryValues="@array/entries"
        android:key="@string/list_preference_1"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="Размер шрифта" />
```

где:

```
<!-- ВЫБОР ШРИФТА -->
<string-array name="entries">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="entry_values">
    <item>Мелкий</item>
    <item>Средний</item>
    <item>Крупный</item>
</string-array>
```

в самом фрагменте настроек `PreferenceFragment` ему можно повесить слушатель в методе `onSharedPreferenceChanged`, например снэкбар для уведомления о том, что настройка изменена:

```
 if (key.equals(getString(R.string.list_preference_1))) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Размер шрифта изменен", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white));
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

А вот так можно вызвать настройку в активности или там где она нужна и привязать к ней нужные текстВью:

```
    private static final int TEXT_SIZE_SMALL = 14, TEXT_SIZE_MID = 18,TEXT_SIZE_LARGE = 22 ;

     private void getSetting() {
        String txt_view_size = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.list_preference_1), "1");
//это значение по умолчанию

if (txt_view_size.contains("2")) {
                txt_view.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_MID);
            } else if (txt_view_size.contains("3")) {
                txt_view.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_LARGE);
            } else {
                txt_view.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_SMALL);
            }
        }
```

так вы получите настройку по умолчанию и возможность менять её через меню настроек